# Percona exited with 10

Tags: liquibase, percona

I got error "Percona exited with 10" when running Liquibase on my database.

I couldn't find the error message anywhere so adding this Q&A so that nobody else has zero search engine hits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My user didn't have permission to create a table.

The list of exit codes is here:
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html#exit-status